# How do I setup Avahi?

Tags: mount, avahi

I want to mount network drives using DNS names, so I'm trying to setup Avahi but I can't find any introduction or baby steps - I am pretty new to Linux.

What is the most basic config and setup required to be able to mount using DNS?

Comment: Avahi is setup in a standard Ubuntu installation. What system are you on?

Comment: I'm using lubuntu on the server and kubuntu on the client. Both recent versions.